# Parse push notification: How to use custom payload

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm using the following json to send a push notification in Parse.

```
{
  "alert": "Push title goes here",
  "sound": "",
  "url": "emap://video/4000"
}
```

The url `emap://video/4000` points to a specific video inside the app if I type that in Safari and hit enter. I want the user to be sent to this video when he clicks on the notification. Why doesn't the above JSON achieve this?

Comment: you stated safari, so i'm assuming your coding for iOS?

Comment: Yes, this is for iOS

Answer (score 1):

So say we are sending this payload :

```
NSDictionary *data = @{
    @"alert" : @"some generic message here",
    @"badge" : @"Increment",
    @"sound" : @"default",
    @"url" : @"emap://video/4000"
};
```

And when the user interacts with it act accordingly :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
      [self handleRemoteNotificationWithPayload:userInfo];
    }
}

-(void)handleRemoteNotificationWithPayload:(NSDictionary *)payload {

    if (payload) {
       NSString *urlLink = [payload valueForKey:@"url"];
       // perform segue or tab bar selectedIndex or open webView whatever you want after checking if user is launching from notification :
    }
}
```

You should also call this in `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in case the users app has been terminated or released from memory:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
...
    NSDictionary *notificationPayload = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    [self handleRemoteNotificationWithPayload:notificationPayload];
...
}
```