# iOS Custom Action When Opening Notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I know that I can set actions for an iOS notification like:

```
UIMutableUserNotificationAction *acceptAction =
    [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];

    acceptAction.identifier = @"THANKS_IDENTIFIER";

    acceptAction.title = @"View News Page";

    // Given seconds, not minutes, to run in the background
    acceptAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground;
    acceptAction.destructive = NO;
    acceptAction.authenticationRequired = NO;

    UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *inviteCategory =
    [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];

    inviteCategory.identifier = @"TAGGED_CATEGORY";

    [inviteCategory setActions:@[acceptAction]
                    forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];
    NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObjects:inviteCategory, nil];

    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                             categories:categories];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
     registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

and include in the payload of the aps a category matching what is listed here, and when the app receives a notification of said category, it will add the action to it, and when that action button is pressed, perform the action here:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification
  completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"THANKS_IDENTIFIER"]) {
        [self handleAcceptActionWithNotification:notification];




    }
    // Must be called when finished
    completionHandler();
}
-(void) handleAcceptActionWithNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification {
    UIAlertView *test = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"YAY" message:@"Success" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [test show];
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
    [self performSelector:@selector(launchNews) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];


}
-(void)launchNews {
    NewsViewController *dvController8 = [[NewsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    [self.tabBarController.navigationController pushViewController:dvController8 animated:YES];
    [dvController8 release];

}
```

However, is there a way that when a push notification of a certain category is received it performs a custom action, without the need of adding in an action button to the notification?

Here is my Payload, using cloudCode:

```
    Parse.Cloud.define("newNews", function(request, response) {

        var theTitle = request.params.articleTitle;


      var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);


        Parse.Push.send({
        where: pushQuery,
        data: {
          alert: "A new article, \"" + theTitle + "\" was just posted.  Open app to view.",



          category : "TAGGED_CATEGORY",

     sound: "default.caf"
        }
      }).then(function() {
          response.success("Push was sent successfully.")
      }, function(error) {
          response.error("Push failed to send with error: " + error.message);
      });

    });

UPDATED CODE:

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
        [self handleRemoteNotificationWithPayload:userInfo];
    }
}
-(void)handleRemoteNotificationWithPayload:(NSDictionary *)payload {
    NSString *thePayload = [payload valueForKey:@"category"];
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hi" message:thePayload delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alertView show];
    if ([thePayload isEqualToString:@"TAGGED_CATEGORY"]) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hi" message:@"Received with category" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alertView show];
        [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:4];
    }
}
```

Comment: I know your not using parse but see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302370/parse-push-notification-how-to-use-custom-payload/32302708#32302708 the same rules apply to local notifications. All you have to do is create a custom dictionary parameter and act accordingly with it when the user taps on it. That way you don't have to use categories if you don't want to

Comment: Thanks.  Actually am using Parse so will check this out

Comment: Tried that, changing out the URL stuff with category, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Did you set it as the custom userInfo for the parse push? You don't actually use any part of the category you don't need to call it. Just set that payload to your parse data dictionary. Can you show how you create the payload without categories

Comment: @soulshined Check the update to OP

Comment: Issue is that     `NSString *thePayload = [payload valueForKey:@"category"];` returns nothing, so no action gets called.  I may send push notifications of other categories, so I just want to make sure that only pushes of a certain category will perform said action

Comment: I didn't know you were sending it via cloud code. I'll have to research that but I'm pretty sure you have to include it as additional parameter of the function not the dictionary. I'll double check

Comment: I set up a log for the payload NSDictionary and got:  `{aps = {alert = "Alert"; category = "TAGGED_CATEGORY"; sound = "default.caf";};}`

Comment: I'm not at a computer. I'm at work so I can't test. So where is that log? client side? So your saying when a user taps on it that log populates the code you just commented on

Comment: I just set up an NSLog for testing, and had it print out the payload that the phone receives when a push notification comes in.

Comment: Right. But what does the log say at the handleRemoteNotification method?

Comment: That's where the log is.

Comment: And it's not changing selected tab index? Sounds like it's working to me

Comment: Right.  I can put other code in that section, like showing a UIAlertView and that will show, but it won't change the tab selected index.

Comment: That's because you haven't set up your tabBar delegate properly. An issue unrelated to the question.

Comment: My delegate is set up properly.  Everything else works in the app.

Comment: Then you should use self.tabBarController.tabBar or whatever it is you set up in your app delegate

Comment: Changing tabs is just a symptom of problem.  My ultimate goal is to push a view controller using the navigation controller that is in each of the tabs.  I couldn't get it to work so I started testing whether or not I could even change tabs, as that seemed to be simpler.

Comment: Show how you set up self.tabBarController please

Comment: `@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    UITabBarController *tabBarController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;`

I then synthesize it in the implementation file.  Then, in didFinish:
` window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
`
I set up my object for UIApplication in xib, set delegate to AppDelegate class, and wire up property I made for it to the TabController in XIB